# The use of modernizr with rotate3d in IE9

Tags: jquery, html, css, rotation, modernizr

I am working on a site that uses

```
.item:hover{
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,-180deg);
}
```

to flip div on hover.

This now needs to be supported in IE9, i was going to use modernizr to check for support:

```
if(!Modernizr.csstransitions) { 

}
```

And then implement the animation but can't get this to work, any suggestions or examples would help alot

Comment: What does not work? Do you get errors in your browser console? What does `alert(Modernizr.csstransitions)` return?

Comment: @Spokey This returned false, i should have said, I put an alert in the if statement to confirm this is false. Not sure if this is the best approach but I cant get the flip to action.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expected. What do you have in that if statement? [IE9 doesn't support transitions](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions) so yeah, false is correct. You need to add a javascript version for the flip in that if statement if you want it to work in IE9. Not sure if that's your complete CSS, but you're missing opera and firefox prefixes

Comment: Modernizer doesn't magically add features to browsers that don't support them